# Cookies through Curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have a thought - is there a possibility to get cookies from a curl POST request to a particular page?

I mean, I create the curl request with post fields, and then get the response of the page - but if the page has some cookies set as HttpOnly I won't be able to see them, right?

cUrl has the possibility to save cookies in a txt file, that's correct I did it and that is fantastic - but how can a split that .txt to save each cookie in a database ?

Comment: You can read `HttpOnly` cookies... You are using `http`. What did you try to store those cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You can store cookies in .TXT which each time will have different name like Time/Date or you can do this.

```
$dir = dirname(__file__);
$config['cookie_file'] = $dir . '/cookies/' . md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . 'txt';
```

This will save all cookies with User's IP in MD5 to COOKIES Folder.

or for directly storing into database.

```
$cookie = tempnam('cookie',rand(000000000,999999999));
```

and the after each request, you can send cookie to Database.

**TIP:** 
cURL(cookie)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);

SQL(storing)

Use `INSERT` for adding cookies to database.